# IIS worker process is getting killed each day at the same time

Tags: iis

We have a problem with our production servers. Worker process restarts each day at 04:00 and 17:30. First restart is scheduled one, defined by our configuration. Second one is a mystery, and we're not sure what's causing it. We tried to add exceptions to McAfee (yes, client has McAfee service installed on their web servers, it's not our call), but it didn't work (we added exceptions for both inetpub directories and w3wp process).

All we have is this message in System event log:

```
Category         : 0
CategoryString   : None
ComputerName     : ************************
Data             : ************************
EventCode        : 7036
EventIdentifier  : 1073748860
EventType        : 3
InsertionStrings : Array[str](('Application Experience', 'running'))
Logfile          : System
Message          : The Application Experience service entered the running state.
RecordNumber     : 536894
SourceName       : Service Control Manager
TimeGenerated    : 20140724173001.406221-000
TimeWritten      : 20140724173001.406221-000
Type             : Information
User             : None
```

I've replaced computer name (for the sake of privacy) and data (for the sake of readability) fields with "*".

Can someone, please, tell me what's the problem here and how to solve it?
If not, I'm going on-site in a week, so does anyone has any suggestions how to figure this out?

Thanks

**EDIT:** I forgot to mention that our application log shows Application_End call at the aforementioned time (17:30) and that our application shuts down gracefully after a few seconds.

Comment: It's unlikely that Application Experience is related to that. Could check for errors around the time it crashes? This message is just informational.

Comment: I've updated the question with additional info. Application is not crashing. Application_End is called, and application gracefully shuts down. No other info in any log file.

Comment: Have you enabled logging of all application pool recycling? http://blogs.iis.net/ganekar/archive/2008/12/12/iis-7-0-application-pool-recycles-log-a-event-in-windows-event-log.aspx  By default less than half of pool recycle reasons are logged.

Comment: @phoebus We tried that and we got no additional info. Also tried with GFlags... nothing. :(

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I tried this approach, but event log showed no entries for silent process exit:

http://bugslasher.net/2011/04/17/who-the-hell-killed-my-process/

So, I'm still looking for solution...

Answer (score 0):

Add those exclusions

**\System32\Inetsrv\

**\IIS Temporary Compressed Files\   (if not under your inetpub directory)

**.*.config

Comment: Can you elaborate?